# Mysql gives me unrelated results

Tags: mysql, select

I  am new in Mysql and have a table where I'm going to select based on an integer column, the problem is that when I use an string on this column! I got no error but it gives me back all rows. for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `News` WHERE Cat='hello' order by id desc limit 20
```

It gives me 20 rows! what's wrong? did I do anything wrong or it's because of something else?

Comment: You said "limit 20" -- so of course it will return you 20 rows. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: As I said the column type is integer but I compare it to an string! that's the question

Comment: Do all these returned rows have Cat=0?

Comment: No, When I'm using integers it works as expected

Comment: Do you pass `WHERE Cat='hello'` only or is there an OR...?

Comment: Only cat='hello',

Comment: If your statement is exactly like the one in the question then the only way to get back  20 rows is if all these 20 rows have Cat=0. If this is not the case then post sample data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's the case it actually gives back the rows with cat=0, but it's normal? can't I prevent mysql to returns columns with 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior for MySql, because in this expression:

```
Cat='hello'
```

what happens is an *implicit conversion* of the string literal `'hello'` to `INTEGER` and as it is described in [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) the result of this conversion is `0`, so the expression is equivalent to:

```
Cat=0
```

If you want to prevent this conversion you could instead convert the column `Cat` to string:

```
WHERE CONVERT(Cat, CHAR) = 'hello'
```

This way the comparison of `Cat` and `'hello'` will be alphanumerical and will fail.
But if you pass a valid integer, then the correct result will be returned.